# ASP FileObject.Name converting to '?'

Tags: iis, vbscript, asp-classic

I have a script that lists all files in a directory, then for each one it will `Response.Write` the name and how many downloads it has.

I have everything completed, but when I went for a test, the files that have "odd" characters in the name are replace with a `?`

I'm guessing, that since some files have foreign languages as there name, and that some have the iPhone emoji icons in the name, that it doesn't recognize it and puts a `?` instead, but this is a serious issue since I can't give the correct file name back to the user, then that incorrect name is fed back into the url to download. (Which doesn't work)

Any suggestions?

Edit:

```
set fs=Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
set fo=fs.GetFolder(Server.MapPath("."))

for each file in fo.files
    if fs.GetExtensionName(file.Path) = "plist" then
        dim tempList, tempName, ...
        tempList = split(file.Name, ".")

        'Manipulate name and data ...

        Response.write(name)
    end if
next
```

The file names themselves have odd characters, and `file.Name` returns a `?` instead of what is actually there.

18アイコン is one example.

Comment: Have you tried using `Server.HTMLEncode` and `Server.URLEncode` on the file names when served to see if it resolves the issue?  Without posting any code, it's not that easy to be of any help.

Comment: Can you post some code please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some code which works fine for me:

```vb
<%@ Language="VBScript" CodePage="65001" %><%

    Option Explicit

    Response.CodePage = 65001
    Response.CharSet = "utf-8"

    Dim fs, fo, file

    Set fs = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set fo = fs.GetFolder(Server.MapPath("."))

    For Each file In fo.files
        If fs.GetExtensionName(file.Path) = "plist" Then
            ' Do whatever here...

            Response.Write file.Name & "<br>"
        End If
    Next
%>
```

If you are using any variables that you didn't dimension beforehand, you'll need to remove the `Option Explicit`; otherwise, VBScript will complain that you didn't dimension them.

**Edit:** I copy & pasted the wrong code; this code works.

Comment: Ok, so it half fixed. It's no longer writing a `?` but it's still not the right characters. NOTE: Some of them are Chinese characters. Maybe a different CodePage? I don't know what other values to use.

Comment: @Jailpod Could you edit your question to include the names of the files which are coming out wrong? Perhaps I'll be able to replicate the problem.

Comment: 18アイコン is one example

Comment: @Jailpod It works fine for me. What operating system and version of IIS are you using?

Comment: Sorry, it did work. I forgot I was encoding the characters with ASCII codes, then decoding it inside of an iOS app. Apparently iOS decodes differently, but it doesn't matter. I just won't encode it anymore. Thanks a lot for your help!